# Can't running EplSite on Windows

Tags: perl

I have problem with running EplSite program. This program is written in Perl. I'm new in Perl. I tried to run it, but Perl command line displays errors. Can you help me? https://sourceforge.net/projects/eplsiteetl/

CODE one of many files: http://pastebin.com/yM9srKGn

Comment: not without the errors you claim to have seen

Comment: Sorry my friend, i don't understand why i'm getting -rep. I wrote that i have problem with running this program. Maybe it's not a problem with only perl. It might be a problem with config of this program. I don't know... For example, when I want to run hypertextperl.pl file, command line show me "LOCATION /" and want to the exit the program. But there are many perl files. I wrote this post, because i tought that someone running this program on Windows and can help me with this.

Comment: Unlikely, you're supposed to show what you're doing, what code causes the problem and what the actual problem is. You say "but Perl command line displays errors" which gives us literally nothing to go on. If you're asking anyone for help, regardless what the subject is, you have to tell them what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't waste your time** with EplSite ETL. There's no useful documentation. I've wasted two days trying to install it with no success. Maybe something would work if there was some info about using hypertextperl.pl (especially with Apache server on Windows) but link to developer's site is dead.

Just find some other software for ETL, because if you somehow manage to install Eplsite ETL you would have to guess how to use it properly. It's not worth the time and effort.